# Android Studio ProGuard minifyEnabled true causes Illegal character error

Tags: android-studio, proguard, illegal-characters

I have create a new empty project and am trying the signed apk file with proguard. My gradle file is like this :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.goldpc.testproguard2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

But when I try to release I get an error message :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.
>
> > java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: f:\Android\sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar

Project is created just for test - it means standard "Hello World" project. I have tried to change `compileSdkVersion` from 21 to 19 but it crashes again. When I disable `proguard` I can create signed apk file. But I need to use it with proguard enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting but i think i found the solution accidentally. When I build project in windows 8 and its system language turkish i gets this error. Then today i install android studio in my mac then when i try to build project without ProGuard android studio gives language error then i searched on net JDK 7 causes error when system language was non-english. Then i changed my computers system languages to english surprisedly it works in two machine with ProGuard , all errors gone.

Comment: That does not makes any sense. These things are getting too weird. I am getting crashes when I comment out minify enabled on my machine.